# How to host a website in Ubuntu server?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, ubuntu-server

In my personal Computer, I installed Ubuntu server. I want to host my website that ubuntu server.What should I do? what are the tools(software) are required? I do not know about this, So i am asking.Anybody know about this, Please clarify. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Start from Apache, it is the web server software.
On internet you will find all the tutorials you need to install it and configure it.

Answer (score 0):

for apache do "sudo apt-get install apache2" then look for /var/www/html directory, after that replace index.html for your own webpage.